# Remote Desktop: How to always enable ClearType in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Every time I log into a machine using RDT I have to go to Adjust ClearType Text from start menu and enable it. And the next time I'll log again, it will be reset. Is there any way to make the setting "stick"?

All my machines are running win7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default settings in Windows 7 Remote Desktop client are for `Low-speed broadband` and font smoothing/ClearType is disabled by default with that settings.

Before connecting click on the `Options` down arrow to expand settings, go to the `Experience` tab and either select `LAN` speed, with would enable all visual enhancements, or if you only want to activate ClearType check `Font smoothing`:

[image: Remote desktop options]

Note that some of the options are saved by remote machine, maybe you need to make this for each machine you connect to (options are saved after a successfully connection).

Comment: Good answer! Quick note of caution though; *if* you use CCleaner with defaults, it'll scrub the settings unless you un-tick 'Remote Desktop' on the Applications list. It's at the bottom.